# Rails + Google Apps - Email Sending Limit Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendmail, google-apps, actionmailer

Currently for sending rails emails we use google apps for our emails, but we're limited to 500 emails/account/day.

I was wondering if there's any way to track how many emails we're sending, and then switch accounts if needed - as in, if we're under 500 emails for the day, use account 1, and if we've hit 500, use account 2, If we hit 999, use account 3 etc.

Is this possible? If there's a plugin that's awesome, if not, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier to just buy a proper account for sending email.

Comment: I agree - it's definitely TONS easier, but not cheaper - however, we have a limited budget, and we might not often go over the 500 limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this solution by creating a proxy class.
The class will be responsible for getting the email delivery request, log the request and forward it to the appropriate Mailer.

This is a very simple prototype, assuming you are using Rails 2.

```
module MailerProxy

  mattr_accessor :emails_count
  @@emails_count = 0

  def self.deliver(klass, method, *args)
    emails_count += 1
    klass.send("deliver_#{method}", *args)
  end

end

MailerProxy.deliver(UserMailer, :email_notification, User.first)
```

Despite the solution above might work, I strongly encourage you to use an appropriate service for sending emails which is able to handle your daily rate instead of trying to create complex workarounds.

Comment: Thanks Simone! So far a lot of the emailing services out there seem to be expensive - postmark seems to be the cheapest - do you have any recommended sites?

Comment: I am having trouble implementing this/thinking about it - 1) How do I specify which smtp to use? Do I need to set up multiple mailers? Also, it needs to be a class, correct?

Comment: 1. Create an array of options and let the class choose the best one. Of course, the example is just a prototype. No, you don't need multiple mailer, just change ActiveMailer settings. No, it doesn't need to be a class.